# Need Panorama App title to be still in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, panorama-control

I would like to have panorama app title to be still when navigating through the panorama items    in Windows Phone 8. Is it possible? If so, How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a Panorama without a Title component and use a separate TextBlock with a big font size as your title. Something like this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock FontSize="48">Some Title<TextBlock>
    <phone:Panorama>
        <!--Some content-->
    <phone:Panorama>
<StackPanel>
```